# How to print css applied background images with WebBrowser control

Tags: c#, .net, printing, registry, webbrowser-control

I am using the webbrowser control in winforms and discovered now that background images which I apply with css are not included in the printouts.

Is there a way to make the webbrowser print the background of the displayed document too?

Edit:
Since I wanted to do this programatically, I opted for this solution:

```
using Microsoft.Win32;

...

RegistryKey regKey = Registry.CurrentUser
                    .OpenSubKey("Software")
                    .OpenSubKey("Microsoft")
                    .OpenSubKey("Internet Explorer")
                    .OpenSubKey("Main");

//Get the current setting so that we can revert it after printjob
var defaultValue = regKey.GetValue("Print_Background");
regKey.SetValue("Print_Background", "yes");

//Do the printing

//Revert the registry key to the original value
regKey.SetValue("Print_Background", defaultValue);
```

Another way to handle this might be to just read the value, and notify the user to adjust this himself before printing. I have to agree that tweaking with the registry like this is not a good practice, so I am open for any suggestions.

Thanks for all your feedback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're going to go and change an important system setting, make sure to first read the current setting and restore it when you are done.

I consider this *very bad* practice in the first place, but if you must do it then be kind.

```
Registry.LocalMachine
```

Also, try changing `LocalUser` instead of `LocalMachine` - that way if your app crashes (and it will), then you'll only confounded the user, not everyone who uses the machine.

Comment: Why is it a very bad practice?

Answer (score 2):

Another registry key would be : 
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\PageSetup\Print_Background
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\PageSetup\Print_Background

Answer (score 1):

The corresponding HKCU key for this setting is:
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\Print_Background

Answer (score 0):

By default, the browser does not print background images at all.

In Firefox

```
* File > Page Setup > Check Off "Print Background"
* File > Print Preview
```

In IE

```
* Tools > Internet Options > Advanced > Printing
* Check Off "Print Background Images and Colors"
```

In Opera

```
* File > Print Options > Check Off "Print Page Background"
* File > Print Preview (You may have to scroll down/up to see it refresh)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var sh = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
key = "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\\Software\\Microsoft\\Internet Explorer\\Main\\Print_Background";
var defaultValue = sh.RegRead(key); 
sh.RegWrite(key,"yes","REG_SZ");
document.frames['detailFrame'].focus(); 
document.frames['detailFrame'].print();
sh.RegWrite(key,defaultValue,"REG_SZ");  
return false;
```